# Library of optimzation algorithms in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for some library(open source will be perfect) that have realization of different optimizaion algorithms in java. Actually I need a dual simplex method. It will be good if it will be documented well.

Comment: I'm looking for a unicorn.  Now we're done sharing what we're looking for, did you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://code.google.com/p/net-fs/.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good index of available Java numerics libraries [here](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/).